# Magento - Add column to customer grid

Tags: magento

how to add a custom column to magento customer grid ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add column to Magento admin catolog > manage products](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990910/add-column-to-magento-admin-catolog-manage-products) (a different grid but same methodology).

Comment: Thanks, and If I want to duplicate the customer grid in a new module.

Comment: Just extend it like any other PHP class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should override the class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid (app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php) and apply the following changes:

1 - add the new attribute to show in the  _prepareCollection() function

2 - add the new column to show in the _prepareColumns() function

Answer (score 1):

Credit: http://www.leonhostetler.com/blog/magento-add-attribute-columns-in-manage-products-grid-201205/

Magento does not provide us with the ability to choose which attributes are included as columns in the Manage Products grid but it’s fairly simple to make the necessary code changes.

The code that generates the Manage Products grid is at /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php. The first thing you need to do is copy Grid.php into to the local directory structure. In other words, you copy Grid.php into the following location; /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/. If there is no such location, then you must create the necessary directories. The final location of the file must be; /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php

Now, open Grid.php (the one in the local directory structure) and begin editing. Find the following code;

> $this->addColumn('sku',
>       array(
>           'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('SKU'),
>           'width' => '80px',
>           'index' => 'sku',
>       ));

That’s the code that adds the SKU column to the product grid.  Now, let’s say you have a custom attribute called Supplier ID (supplier_ID) and you want these to appear on the Manage Products grid as well. Place the following code either before or after the above block of code, as long as it’s inside _prepareColumns().

> ```
> $this->addColumn('supplier_id',
>     array(
>         'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Supplier ID'),
>         'width' => '150px',
>         'index' => 'supplier_id',
>     ));
> ```

Then add the following line to _prepareCollection() where the other attributes are listed like this;

> ->addAttributeToSelect('supplier_id')

That should be all you need to do. You might have to re-compile, refresh your caches, logout, and log back in to see the change in your product grid.

The above example is for adding an attribute with a Catalog Input Type for Store Owner of Text Field. What if your attribute uses a dropdown list? The code above will have to be modified.

Let’s say you have an attribute called Supplier (supplier) which in the product editor presents a dropdown list of suppliers to choose from. To do this, we can add the following code to _prepareColumns():

> $supplier_items =
>   Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')->getCollection()->setStoreFilter()->join('attribute','attribute.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id',
>   'attribute_code'); foreach ($supplier_items as $supplier_item) :
>       if ($supplier_item->getAttributeCode() == 'supplier')
>           $supplier_options[$supplier_item->getOptionId()] = $supplier_item->getValue(); endforeach;   $this->addColumn('supplier',
>       array(
>           'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('supplier'),
>           'width' => '150px',
>           'type'  => 'options',
>           'index' => 'supplier',
>           'options' => $supplier_options, ));

And let’s not forget to add the following line to _prepareCollection() where the other attributes are listed like this;

> ->addAttributeToSelect('supplier')

That should do it for you. Re-compile, refresh your caches, and logout and then back in if you need to.

Comment: This is a well put together answer however I'm giving it a down vote because it entirely fails to acknowledge that the question asked was about adding a column to the Customer Grid, not the Products Grid. Granted the process is nearly the same, this answer does not even make an attempt to at least mention that the customer grid is found under app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php.

Alas, I do not have the reputation at the moment to down vote. So instead I suggest that the answer at least be revised.

Answer (score 1):

I have publish [here](http://magentoquiz.com/question/how-to-add-column-to-customer-grid-in-magento-adminhtml/) with real example.

If you need to add custome attribute, you may need to take care of join statements carefully.

```
->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite customer grid block with your custom module.

**app/code/[local or community]/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <yourcompany_yourmodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </yourcompany_yourmodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_grid>YourCompany_YourModule_Block_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/[local or community]/YourCompany/YourModule/Block/Customer/Grid.php**

```
<?php

class YourCompany_YourModule_Block_Customer_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid
{
    public function setCollection($collection)
    {
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('confirmation');                    
        parent::setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        parent::_prepareColumns();

        $this->addColumn('confirmation', array(
                'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Confirmed'),
                'index' => 'confirmation',
                'type'  => 'text',
                'width' => '100px',
        ));
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

Detailed explanation can be found here:

http://tipsmagento.blogspot.com/2011/03/add-new-column-on-customers-grid.html

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to check out TigerMin for Magento. It's a tool with which you can easily add columns to productsgrid and even inline edit values instantly. Here`s a live demo: http://demo.emvee-solutions.com/tigermin/