# Magento customer attribute

Tags: php, magento

I have made a `customer` attribute. It shows up directly on:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Grid.php
```

Well that's great. But I want to display that attribute on the order grid (`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php`) Whatever I do. It won't be displayed on the grid.

Can someone tell me how to fix this? It drives me crazy all day.

Comment: is that attribute selected in your collection?

Comment: A&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990910/add-column-to-magento-admin-catolog-manage-products#5994209

Comment: @FlorinelChisNo I think not. And joinAttribute or addAttributeToSelect won't work...