# Rewrite admin block that is rewriten by other extension

Tags: magento

I try to rewrite sales_order_view
Here is what I have in config.xml

```
        <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view>Bitstream_FancourierSelfawb_Block_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
        <bitstream_selfawb>
            <class>Bitstream_FancourierSelfawb_Block</class>
        </bitstream_selfawb>
    </blocks>
```

Ofcorse, I have the proper file in Bitstream/FancourierSelfawb/Block

All I need is to add a button but looking over other modules I see that block is already overwritten.

```
        <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view>Fooman_EmailAttachments_Block_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
```

If I comment this in config.xml from Fooman module I can see my button. Otherwise, no luck.
Is there a way to overwrite same block twice in different module?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `app/etc/modules/Bitstream_FancourierSelfawb.xml` add a `depends` node.

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bitstream_FancourierSelfawb>
            ...
            <depends>
                <Fooman_EmailAttachments />
            </depends>
        </Bitstream_FancourierSelfawb>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Of course your `Bitstream_FancourierSelfawb_Block_View` class will have to extend `Fooman_EmailAttachments_Block_View` directly instead of the Mage original.

---

If you want your addition to work both with and without the Fooman extension then you'll have to resort to a lengthier [event-based method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5994209/471559).

Comment: Thank you. I think it's a bit stupid that once an extension rewrite a view you have no way in knowing this (maybe profile?).

Comment: When working with blocks you can use [template hints](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/) to also find out the class name. I agree there is no tool provided for detecting rewritten models. The only way I know is to use `echo get_class(Mage::getModel('example/example'));`

Comment: Yep, `get_class()` is my new favorite function since I'm working with Magento…