# Magento: how do I add a column to products selection in admin category page?

Tags: magento

I would like to change the admin category page so that in the products tab I also have the product type as a column. In that way I will be able to rapidly add configurable master products without having to sift through their simple child products.

An alternative option - or additional column - would be to have the visibility column with the usual catalog/search, search, catalog options.

I have tried @clockworkgeek's intro to the topic here: [Add column to Magento admin catolog > manage products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990910/add-column-to-magento-admin-catolog-manage-products)
But I need more pointers at the 'add sql here' part.

Answer (score 0):

you should add this file: app/code/local/[your company]/[you app]/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Setup.php

```
class [YourNameSpace]_[YourModule]_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup extends  Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup{

    public function  getDefaultEntities(){
        return array(
            'catalog_product' => array(
                'entity_model'      => 'catalog/product',
                'attribute_model'   => 'catalog/resource_eav_attribute',
                'table'             => 'catalog/product',
                'additional_attribute_table' => 'catalog/eav_attribute',
                'entity_attribute_collection' => 'catalog/product_attribute_collection',

                'attributes'        => array(
                    '**Name of your column 1**' => array(
                        'type'              => 'varchar',
                        'backend'           => '',
                        'frontend'          => '',
                        'label'             => 'Your Column Label ...',
                        'input'             => 'text',
                        'class'             => '',
                        'source'            => '',
                        'global'            => 1,
                        'group'             =>'General',
                        'visible'           => true,
                        'required'          => false,
                        'user_defined'      => true,
                        'default'           => '',
                        'searchable'        => true,
                        'filterable'        => true,
                        'comparable'        => false,
                        'visible_on_front'  => false,
                        'unique'            => false,
                        'visible_in_advanced_search' => true,
                        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                        'used_for_sort_by' => true,
                    ),

                    // your other columns...

                )
            )
        );
    }
}
```

you need remove your module from table core_resource first.
then edit file [you module]/etc/config.xml, add this code in global area:

.......

```
<resources>
    <[your_module_name_in_lowercase]_setup>
        <setup>
             <module>[YourNamespace]_[YourModuleName]</module>
                  <class>
                        [YourNamespace]_[YourModuleName]_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup
                  </class>                  
    </setup>
    <connection>
    <use>core_setup</use>               
    </connection>
    </[your_module_name_in_lowercase]_setup>
<[your_module_name_in_lowercase]_write>
    <connection>
    <use>core_write</use>           
    </connection>       
</[your_module_name_in_lowercase]_write>
<[your_module_name_in_lowercase]_read>
    <connection>
    <use>core_read</use>            
    </connection>       
</[your_module_name_in_lowercase]_read>
</resources>
```

...........

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there is a lot to be said for using a local over-ride rather than trying to write yet another module.

I solved my problem by making a local copy of the file that does the product grid: app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category/Tab/Product.php

I added this line immediately after after the product collection is prepared:

```
        $collection->joinAttribute(
            'visibility',
            'catalog_product/visibility',
            'entity_id',
            null,
            'inner'
        );
```

Then in 'prepareColumns' function I added:

```
    $this->addColumn('visibility',
        array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Visibility'),
            'width' => '70px',
            'index' => 'visibility',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'options' => Mage::getModel('catalog/product_visibility')->getOptionArray(),
    ));
```

This now means that I have my catalogue/search, not visible individually options in the grid.

The template for how to add columns is the normal product grid: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php