# How to add category filtering on product list in magento Admin?

Tags: magento, filter, filtering

I am working on Magento 1.5. I have two main categories in my store lets say Products and Utilities.

```
Products
   - Product 1
   - Product 2
Utilities
   - Utility 1
   - Utility 2
```

I need to add a dropdown which allows me to filter using these two categories on product list table just like product type dropdown which allows me to filter using product type.

I want to implement in admin Panel. Does any one have any idea?
Please Help...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990910/add-column-to-magento-admin-catolog-manage-products

Answer (score -1):

You can add a drop down in the template with an onChange event bound to changing `window.location.href`. The destination URLs can be generated in the same was as in the  layered navigation (left side in the product list where you can click a category).

Sample URL: `/furniture.html?cat=22`

Comment: Hi alex, Thanks for your reply. But I want to implement in Admin panel(I must have added that in the Question) not on Front End.